# promote results in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I searched in the documentation for a way to promote ElasticSearch results if a specific field has a certain value, but I didn't find any good practice, for example, I have a user that lives in Paris if the user search for a query I want the documents that are relevant to Paris to appear the first or just to be promoted.

Comment: A good idea would be to show what you've tried so far and that doesn't work.

Comment: I didn't try anything since I didn't find any way to do so !

Comment: I would start [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/controlling-relevance.html), that are some very interesting techniques.

Comment: if you are looking something simple, tag the documents and the users, same tags, so when the user with tag 'paris' searches you boost the results with documents tagged with the user's tags, for instance: 'paris'.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I didn't see that part, very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot to this but you want to research "boosting". This can be done at the  [mapping level](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-boost.html) or the [query level](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_boosting_query_clauses.html).

Mapping example:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "location": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "boost": 2 <--- 2x boost to the final score
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Query Example:

```
GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "match": {  
                    "content": {
                        "query":    "full text search",
                        "operator": "and"
                    }
                }
            },
            "should": [
                { "term": {
                    "location": {
                        "value": "xxx",
                        "boost": 3 <--- 3x boost if the location matches
                    }
                }}
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Worth noting, though, that index-time boosting (i.e. at the mapping level) [has been deprecated in ES 5](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-boost.html) (the link explains why it is a bad idea). You should favor search-time boosting instead whenever possible.

Comment: I think this is what I want, Thank you !

Comment: @val thanks for the comment. I still work heavily in 5.x so I forgot about that.